# how can pass mysql array to jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, parsing

I have a PHP file that gets data from database table and sends it to jQuery AJAX:

```
include '../../Connections/Base.php';   

$query = "SELECT codemeli,name,family FROM members ORDER BY id ASC";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo  json_encode($row);  
    }
} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

and jQuery code is:

```
$("#generate").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "postpon/signup/showMeliCode.php",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Before Parse");  // It's work
            response = $.parseJSON(response); // don't work
            alert(responde);   // don't work
        }
    })

})
```

as you know `$.parseJSON` doesn't work.
Why `parseJSON` not working?

Comment: are you getting the text "Before Parse" in alert box ?

Comment: yes i get it but alert after parseJSON don't work

Comment: You are not generating correct json. you need to either use echo  json_encode($result->fetch_all()); instead of while loop or add all rows to preallocated array and then output it after while loop. Also ensure that you do not print any debug information along with json

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [`$.parseJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) is deprecated.

> As of jQuery 3.0, `$.parseJSON` is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use
>   the native `JSON.parse` method instead.

You need to output the result set instead of outputting rows individually:

```
include '../../Connections/Base.php';   

$query = "SELECT codemeli,name,family FROM members ORDER BY id ASC";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
} else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => $mysqli->error]);
}
```

```
$("#generate").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'postpon/signup/showMeliCode.php',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```